# Can I specify a remote database in SQLALCHEMY_BINDS?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Tables must have `__bind_key__` specified. But I need to work with a remote database that is not created in my Flask app.

Is there an option to use something like this:

```
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
        'remote': REMOTE_DB_URL
    }

data = db.session.execute(query, binds='remote')
```

?

I have not found such examples.

Comment: I resolved it. session = db.session
        session.bind = db.get_engine(current_app, 'remote')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session = db.session 
session.bind = db.get_engine(current_app, 'remote')
data = session.execute(query)
```